# MySQL left join structure not returning months with 0 orders

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

- shine_orders
- LU_CALENDAR

For context:

- LU_CALENDAR is essentially a table containing all possible dates in a range. It has a days column called Calendar_date with all datestamps such as 2000-01-01.
- shine_orders contains my orders, with a dt column that has a datetime stamp such as "2011-06-15 10:54:09".

I'm trying to return a value for all months in a range, even if for a particular app_id in shine_orders there are no rows on some months. The latter is what I'm struggling with. I can't get it to return data where the result was 0.

SQL Statement so far:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dt, '%b %y') as dtstr, COUNT(*) 
FROM shine_orders 
LEFT JOIN LU_CALENDAR
ON Date(shine_orders.dt) = LU_CALENDAR.Calendar_Date
WHERE shine_orders.type = 'PayPal' 
    AND shine_orders.app_id = '5' 
    AND DATE_ADD(LU_CALENDAR.Calendar_Date, INTERVAL 2 YEAR) > NOW()

GROUP BY dtstr 
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(dt, '%y%m') ASC
```

Example output:

[image]

Would anybody here have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to do the trick:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(LU_CALENDAR.Calendar_Date, '%b %y') as dtstr, IFNULL(COUNT(shine_orders.id),0) as COUNT
    FROM shine_orders 

    RIGHT JOIN LU_CALENDAR
    ON LU_CALENDAR.Calendar_Date = Date(shine_orders.dt)
    AND shine_orders.app_id = '5' 
    WHERE LU_CALENDAR.Calendar_Date 
    BETWEEN DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW() , INTERVAL 2 year)) AND DATE(NOW())

    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(LU_CALENDAR.Calendar_Date, '%y%m') 
    ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(LU_CALENDAR.Calendar_Date, '%y%m') ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, you appear to have all the months in your example output. But I understand that your question is that there are some months that are skipped because the example output is zero.

I think that a right join will be appropriate instead of a left join in this case, which should mean that every row in the field calendar_date gets shown. Also, since you are right joining onto the table LU_CALENDAR, you need to make sure you group by something in LU_CALENDAR; so for your first line try:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Calendar_Date, '%b %y') as dtstr, COUNT(*)
```

Comment: Something like this? `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(LU_CALENDAR.Calendar_Date, '%b %y') as dtstr, COUNT(*)
FROM shine_orders 

RIGHT JOIN LU_CALENDAR
ON Date(shine_orders.dt) = LU_CALENDAR.Calendar_Date 

WHERE (shine_orders.app_id = '5')
 AND DATE_ADD(LU_CALENDAR.Calendar_Date, INTERVAL 2 YEAR) > NOW()

GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(LU_CALENDAR.Calendar_Date, '%y%m') 
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(LU_CALENDAR.Calendar_Date, '%y%m') ASC`

Comment: I'm still getting the same result with the above statement